# WHERE query in JPQL is not translating to correct native query

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpql

The complex WHERE query with OR condition is not translated correctly to native query

JPQL query condition:

```
WHERE i.id = :id AND ( (i.group = 1 ) OR (i.group != 1 and i.orderDate > :todaysDate))
```

is being translated as

```
where item.id=? 

    and (
        item.group=1 
        or item.group<>1 
        and item.due_date>?
    )
```

We can observe that the second condition of AND is not being evaluated in correct order. How to deal with complex where queries in JPQL

Instead i believe **it should ideally would have been**

```
where item.id=? 

    and (
        item.group=1 
        or 
     (item.group<>1 
        and item.due_date>?)
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

The `AND` operator is evaluated before the `OR` operator when there are no round brackets.

Unless you are saying that this is not the case in the database you are using, there is no difference between the two queries.